# Form Layout is not flexible on mobile devices

Tags: css, vaadin, vertical-scrolling, vaadin14

I'm testing a registration screen of my vaadin application on my mobile device ( huawei p30 pro ). For registration process I use a form "iron-form" element. I put this into a vertical layout. In general, there is always a navigation bar in the screen. On desktop view, navbar appears at top, and on mobile devices it appears in the bottom of the screen. However when I open the keyboard(Softkeyboard of android) the navigation bar is pushed upwards on top of the screen and the vertical layout  for the registration form doesn't behave sensibly, in the sense that i cant scroll inside vertical layout. For example, When I open the keyboard, if i go down to register button, I cant scroll up to username text field on top of the screen. The navbar overlaps with the view(Realized in the second picture, the textfield above the email field is not visible and scrollable). How could I fix this? Thanks in advance..

[image]
After the keyboard is opened

My registration page looks as follows:

```
@Route(value = "registration", layout = MainView.class)
@RouteAlias(value = "registration", layout = MainView.class)
@CssImport("./styles/views/login/registration.css")
public class Registration extends Div implements AfterNavigationObserver {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -1223086666624645746L;

public Registration() {
    UI.getCurrent().getPage().executeJs("document.getElementById('submitbutton')"
            + ".addEventListener('click', () => document.getElementById('ironform').submit());");

    Element ironForm = createRegistrationFormComponent();
    getElement().appendChild(ironForm);

    setClassName("registration-view");
}

private Element createRegistrationFormComponent() {
    VerticalLayout loginLayout = new VerticalLayout();
    loginLayout.setClassName("registration-form-layout");
    loginLayout.add(createUsernameLabel(), createUsernameField(), createEmailLabel(), createEmailField(),
            createPasswordLabel(), createPasswordField(), createPasswordLabel2(), createPasswordField2(),
            createRegisterButton());
    
    FormLayout formLayout = new FormLayout();
    formLayout.add(loginLayout);

    Element formElement = new Element("form");

    formElement.setAttribute("method", "post");
    formElement.setAttribute("action", "login");
    formElement.appendChild(formLayout.getElement());

    Element ironForm = new Element("iron-form");

    ironForm.setAttribute("id", "ironform");
    ironForm.setAttribute("allow-redirect", true);

    ironForm.appendChild(formElement);
    return ironForm;
}
```

My css file for registration form is as follows:

```
.registration-view {
display: flex;
vertical-align: middle;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow-y: auto;
background-color: var(--lumo-shade-5pct);}

.registration-form-layout {
vertical-align: right;
align-items: right;
justify-content: right;}

.submitButton {
width: 100%;
background-color: var(--lumo-success-color);
color: white;
margin-bottom: 55px }
```

Also my css file for the navbar

```
.navbar {
width: 100%; //
fallback width: 100vw;
padding-right: 2%;
padding-left: 1%;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please add the code that shows the problem.  And maybe a screenshot,
that shows the problem.

Comment: @cfrick Hey, thank you for the suggestion, I just updated the question, can you pls look again?

Comment: Hi @cfrick, did you have a chance to look ?:(